# How to create a make-curry function like racket has

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, currying, sicp

I would like to see how it might be possible to emulate the `(curry func)` that `racket` provides. Here is an example of how I'm manually currying a function:

```
#lang sicp
; convert to a curried function

(define (add1 x y) (+ x y))

(define add2
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (y)
      (+ x y))))
```

```
(add1 2 3)
; 5

((add2 2) 3)
; 5
```

Where would I start to add a higher-order function such that it converts a 'normal' function into a curried function, something like this:

```
(((curry add1) 2) 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make some tradeoffs because it's not easy to tell how many parameters a function accepts. Racket has a `procedure-arity` function that lets `curry` tell how many arguments to curry, but the SICP language does not. So you have to choose how to handle this. Some reasonable choices include:

- Make the caller specify how many arguments to wait for
- Work only with a fixed number of arguments
- Curry only the first *n* calls to a function, and have the *n+1*th call through the underlying function.

Comment: I see, so if the caller specified the number of arguments (say, two) or it was fixed at something (also could be two) what might be an example of how that could work?

Comment: To fix at 2 is pretty simple. Just write it as you wrote `add1`, but instead of hardcoding `+` you use another lambda taking `f` as an argument.

Comment: ah I see, yea that one is pretty easy. How would #1 would be?

Comment: Try working it out yourself. Obviously the function takes an int and a function as a parameter, and if the int is zero it can just return the function. For a nonzero int, it clearly returns some other function, and that function probably calls curry itself with a smaller int.

Comment: thanks for the encouragement and tips, yes I'll try working this one out...

Comment: FWIW, you probably need to create a helper function that additionally accepts an accumulator, which is a list of arguments to be applied.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase yea, seems a bit over my head...I wrote up what I have and asked a new questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012640/going-from-curry-0-1-2-to-n