# Going from Curry-0, 1, 2, to ...n

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

Following up from a previous question I asked about writing a curry function, [How to create a make-curry function like racket has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68011489/how-to-create-a-make-curry-function-like-racket-has), I've started writing the fixed case for 0, 1, 2 -- they are very similar to Church Numerals which is pretty neat. Here is what I have so far:

```
(define (curry-0 func)
  func)

(define hello (begin (display "Hello!") (newline)))
(curry-0 hello)
; Hello!
```

```
(define (curry-1 func)
  (lambda (x)
      (func x )))

((curry-1 -) 2)
; -2
```

```
(define (curry-2 func)
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (y)
      (func x y))))

(((curry-2 +) 2) 3)
5
```

The pattern seems to be:

```
(define curry-n func
     (lambda (x1)
        (lambda (x2)
           ...
            (lambda (xn)
                (func x1 x2 ... xn)
```

However, I'm having some trouble 'building up' the n-nested lambda expression. I suppose I could build a nested lambda with something like:

```
(define (curry-n num func)
     (if (num > 0)
         (lambda (?) (curry-n (- num 1) func))))
```

But I'm not sure how I would 'bind' the variables to each lambda function and also how I would end up passing those same variables (in order) to the `(func x1 x2 ... xn)` function.

This is incorrect but I've started along the lines of...

```
(define (curry-n num func)
 (if (> num 0)
      ; but lambda won't accept a number, possible to string-format?
      (curry-n (- num 1) (lambda (num)))))
```

How could this be done?

Comment: as shown, `(curry-0 hello)` couldn't have produced that output, `; Hello!`. only `((curry-0 hello))` could do that.

Comment: also, this has nothing to do with Church encoding, except the functions being nested lambdas taking one argument at a time. i.e. "curried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using a loop**

You need some sort of `loop` to collect each `arg` from the `lambda` -

```scm
(define (curry-n num f)
  (let loop
    ((n num)
     (args null))
    (lambda ((arg null))
      (cond ((= n 0)
             (apply f (reverse args)))
            ((= n 1)
             (apply f (reverse (cons arg args))))
            (else
             (loop (- n 1) (cons arg args)))))))
```

`curry` should *always* return a procedure, so you can see `loop` will *always* return a `lambda`, even for the `num = 0` case. Each `arg` is `cons`'d onto `args`, creating a reversed list of arguments. This is why we `reverse` the `args` before `apply`ing the user-supplied procedure, `f`.

It works like this -

```scm
(define (hello)
  (println "hello world"))

((curry-n 0 hello))
```

```scm
"hello world"
```

```scm
((((curry-n 3 +) 10) 20) 30)
```

```scm
60
```

---

**using delimited continuations**

In the spirit of sharing learning exercises, take some time to review this example using [delimited continuations](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html) -

```scm
(require racket/control)

(define (curry-3 f)
  (reset (f (shift k k) (shift k k) (shift k k))))

(define (hello a b c)
  (printf "hello world ~a ~a ~a\n" a b c))

((((curry-3 hello) 10) 20) 30)
```

```scm
hello world 10 20 30
```

To get `curry-n` all we need to do is build a list of `n` continuations!

```scm
(require racket/control)

(define (curry-n n f)
  (reset (apply f (build-list n (lambda (_) (shift k k))))))
```

And it works just like our first one -

```scm
(define (hello a b c)
  (printf "hello world ~a ~a ~a\n" a b c))

((((curry-n 3 hello) 10) 20) 30)
```

```scm
"hello world 10 20 30"
```

```scm
((((((curry-n 5 +) 10) 20) 30) 40) 50)
```

```scm
150
```

You can visualize the process as working something like this, where each `__` is a "hole" to fill -

```
(f __ __ __)
    \
     \_ (lambda (x)
          (f x __ __))
                \
                 \_ (lambda (y)
                      (f x y __))
                              \
                               \_ (lambda (z)
                                    (f x y z))
```

The only difference is there are `n` holes to fill, so we build a list of `n` holes and `apply` -

```scm
(build-list 3 (lambda (_) (shift k k)))
```

```
(list __
       \
        \_ (lambda (x)
              (list x __
                       \
                        \_ (lambda (y)
                             (list x y __
                                        \
                                         \_ (lambda (z)
                                              (list x y z))
```

```scm
(apply f (list x y z)
```

**scheme**

I didn't notice you were doing this work in Scheme. We can define `build-list` -

```scm
(define (build-list n f)
  (let loop
    ((m 0))
    (if (>= m n)
        '()
        (cons (f m) (loop (+ m 1))))))
```

And we can use Olivier Danvy's original implementation of [shift/reset](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/scheme/src/scsh-0.4.2/misc/shift-reset.scm),

```scm
(define-syntax reset
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ?e) (reset-thunk (lambda () ?e)))))

(define-syntax shift
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ?k ?e) (call/ct (lambda (?k) ?e)))))

(define *meta-continuation*
  (lambda (v)
    (error "You forgot the top-level reset...")))

(define abort
  (lambda (v)
    (*meta-continuation* v)))

(define reset-thunk
  (lambda (t)
    (let ((mc *meta-continuation*))
      (call-with-current-continuation
        (lambda (k)
      (begin
        (set! *meta-continuation* (lambda (v)
                    (begin
                      (set! *meta-continuation* mc)
                      (k v))))
        (abort (t))))))))

(define call/ct
  (lambda (f)
    (call-with-current-continuation
      (lambda (k)
    (abort (f (lambda (v)
            (reset (k v)))))))))
```

Our `curry-n` can stay the same -

```scm
(define (curry-n n f)
  (reset (apply f (build-list n (lambda (_) (shift k k))))))

((((((curry-n 5 +) 10) 20) 30) 40) 50)
```

```scm
150
```

Comment: ha, that's pretty neat. Can you explain the `reset` and the whole `shift k k` thing? Is that sort of like vim where you do something like `nmap <leader>k ...` ?

Comment: also, what does `(let loop ((n num) (args null))` do? I've only seen a `let` used something like `(let ((a 1) (b 2)) ...)`

Comment: That is a [named let](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29). `let loop ((a 1) (b2)) <body>)` is the same as `(define (loop a b) <body>) (loop 1 2)`

Comment: `shift` and `reset` are control operators. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation) offers a fairly approachable explanation. Given `(* 2 (reset (+ 1 (shift k ...))))`, `k` or whatever you decide to name it, represents the continuation up to the `reset` boundary. Here you can think of `k` as `(lambda (x) (+ 1 x)`. Applying `k` would resume the computation with its argument, ie `(k 5)` would result in `(* 2 (+ 1 5))`. With our program, `(reset (myfunc (shift k k))` builds a continuation like `(lambda (x) (myfunc x)`.

Comment: The interesting thing is you can decide not to apply the continuation `(* 2 (reset (+ 1 (shift k 3))))` results in `(* 2 3)`. This is because the `(+ 1 ...)` portion represented by `k` is not applied and instead `3` is returned. Another interesting thing is you can apply `k` multiple times, `(* 2 (reset (+ 1 (shift k (k (k (k 5)))))))` results in `(* 2 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 5))))` as the `(+ 1 ...)`. The wikipedia page contains other powerful demonstrations.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers may be a bit more efficient as they accumulate a concrete list of parameters, or fancier because they allow you to take multiple arguments at once, but in my opinion it is a better learning exercise, and simpler, to just write a basic function that takes one argument at a time with no need for an accumulator.

```
(define (curry n f)
  (cond ((= n 1) f)
        (else (lambda (x)
                (curry (- n 1)
                       (lambda args
                          (apply f (cons x args))))))))

 > (((curry 2 +) 5) 4)
=> 9
```

Instead of accumulating parameters, we just create a new lambda that expects fewer parameters each time, and curry that. It behaves very much like the generalization of your attempts for fixed `n`. It's the same basic approach as rawrex's (perfectly reasonable) answer, but without the fancy facility to handle args in larger chunks.

Comment: how fun! i love the simplicity of this compared to my `loop` answer. in the spirit of sharing learning exercises i added another technique which exposes each argument as a continuation :D

Comment: @amalloy -- that's really neat, thank you. Could you explain how this part here works -- `(lambda args (apply f (cons x args)))` ?

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: @amalloy basically why is it `(apply f (cons x args))` instead of just `(apply f args)` ? What does the `x` represent here?

Comment: The point is that each lambda captures a single argument. We go from a 5-argument function to a 4-argument function with one argument "baked in", then to a 3-argument function with two baked in...and so on until we get to just a one-argument function with 4 baked in.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write the following function instead:

```
;; create `num` nested lambdas, where the body applies `func` to
;; `args-so-far` along with the arguments of those nested lambdas
(define (curry-n* func num args-so-far)
  ...)
```

Here's its usage:

```
(define (sub-4 a b c d)
  (- a b c d))

(curry-n* sub-4 0 (list 10 1 2 3)) 
;=> should evaluate to 10 - 1 - 2 - 3 = 4

(curry-n* sub-4 1 (list 10 1 2)) 
;=> should evaluate to a procedure that accepts x, 
;   and returns 10 - 1 - 2 - x = 7 - x

(curry-n* sub-4 2 (list 10 1)) 
;=> should evaluate to a procedure that accepts x, 
;   and returns a procedure that accepts y, 
;   and returns 10 - 1 - x - y = 9 - x - y
```

For the base case (`num` = 0), you will want to use the function `apply`.

Once you have `curry-n*`, you can then create `curry-n` which invokes `curry-n*` as a helper function.

---

Once you have the solution, you will notice that it is not quite efficient. You can revise `curry-n*` to flip `args-fo-far` around, so that its usage is like this:

```
(define (sub-4 a b c d)
  (- a b c d))

(curry-n* sub-4 0 (list 3 2 1 10)) 
;=> should evaluate to 4

(curry-n* sub-4 1 (list 2 1 10)) 
;=> should evaluate to a procedure that accepts x, 
;   and returns 7 - x

(curry-n* sub-4 2 (list 1 10)) 
;=> should evaluate to a procedure that accepts x, 
;   and returns a procedure that accepts y, 
;   and returns 9 - x - y
```

Comment: what's the function though, all you have is `...` ?

Comment: That's an exercise for you to do.