# The apply function in SICP/Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, apply, sicp

I've asked a few questions here about Scheme/SICP, and quite frequently the answers involve using the `apply` procedure, which I haven't seen in SICP, and in the book's Index, it only lists it one time, and it turns out to be a footnote.

Some examples of usage are basically every answer to this question: [Going from Curry-0, 1, 2, to ...n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012640/going-from-curry-0-1-2-to-n).

I am interested in how `apply` works, and I wonder if some examples are available. How could the apply procedure be re-written into another function, such as rewriting `map` like this?

```
#lang sicp

(define (map func sequence)
    (if (null? sequence) nil
        (cons (func (car sequence)) (map func (cdr sequence)))))
```

It seems maybe it just does a function call with the first argument? Something like:

```
(apply list '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; --> (list 1 2 3 4 5)
(apply + '(1 2 3))        ; --> (+ 1 2 3)
```

So maybe something similar to this in Python?

```
>>> args=[1,2,3]
>>> func='max'
>>> getattr(__builtins__, func)(*args)
3
```

Comment: Scheme doesn't have `nil`, that's Lisp.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using `#lang sicp`

Comment: SICP is a textbook, not a language.

Comment: @Barmar yes but it's also an option in DrRacket: https://gyazo.com/28836fa26506a63c1c9d5dbb8ec9a386 and https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked to see how  `apply` could be coded, not  how it can be used.

It [can be coded as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910496/849891)

```
#lang sicp

; (define (appl f xs)    ; #lang racket
;   (eval 
;     (cons f (map (lambda (x) (list 'quote x)) xs))))

(define (appl f xs)      ; #lang r5rs, sicp
  (eval
    (cons f (map (lambda (x) (list 'quote x)) 
                 xs))
    (null-environment 5)))
```

Trying it out in Racket under `#lang sicp`:

```
> (display (appl list '(1 2 3 4 5)))
(1 2 3 4 5)

> (display (     list   1 2 3 4 5 ))
(1 2 3 4 5)

> (appl + (list (+ 1 2) 3))
6

> (     +       (+ 1 2) 3 )
6

> (display (appl map (cons list '((1 2 3)  (10 20 30)))))
((1 10) (2 20) (3 30))

> (display (     map       list  '(1 2 3) '(10 20 30)  ))
((1 10) (2 20) (3 30))
```

Here's the link to the docs about [`eval`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-9.html?q=eval#%25_idx_600).

It requires an *environment* as the second argument, so we supply it with `(null-environment 5)` which just returns an empty environment, it looks like it. We don't actually need any environment here, as the evaluation of the arguments has already been done at that point.

Comment: thanks, that `5` is pretty odd in the procedure call, but it seems that's just the version (if so, why can't the implementation just figure that out itself?) Also, do you want to add a link to the answer for the `null-environment` as well?

Comment: it's the same link. :) just scroll down few lines, it's literally the next entry. :)

Answer (score 2):

`apply` is used when you want to call a function with a dynamic number of arguments.

Your `map` function only allows you to call functions that take exactly one argument. You can use `apply` to map functions with different numbers of arguments, using a variable number of lists.

```
(define (map func . sequences)
  (if (null? (car sequences))
      '()
      (cons (apply func (map car sequences))
            (apply map func (map cdr sequences)))))

(map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
;; Output: (5 7 9)
```

Comment: thanks, should that say `map` though instead of apply? (I get an error when trying to do `apply +`.)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.