# Alternate way to do an 'apply'

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, apply, sicp

If I have a function and also a list of arguments, I can use `apply` like this:

```
(apply func args)
```

For example:

```
(apply + '(1 2 3))
```

Now, if I define the function `func` and a list of arguments `args` as follows:

```
(define func +)
(define args '(1 2 3))
```

why then doesn't the following work to run the function:

```
(append (list func) args)
(cons func args)          ; same thing
; (#<procedure:+> 1 2 3)
```

I would think the `append` would create `(+ 1 2 3)` just as `(append '(1) '(2 3))` creates `(1 2 3)`.

Why doesn't that occur, and is there a way to use `append` to 'act like' the `apply`, as I'm trying to do above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does occur. Both `(append (list func) args)` and `(cons func args)` do create the same list, `(#<procedure:+> 1 2 3)`.

But it's just a list, a piece of data. To "run" it, you need to  evaluate it:

```
> (eval (cons func args) (null-environment 5))
6

> (eval (append (list func) args) (null-environment 5))
6
```

Comment: I see, so doing `eval` and `apply` are almost like two sides of the coin, and would be done with: `(apply + '(1 2))` vs `(eval (cons + '(1 2)) <null-env>)` ?

Comment: `eval` is pretty tough to use correctly. It works for simple cases like lists of numbers because `1` evaluates to itself, and so there's no difference between `'1` and `1`. But in general you would need to quote the arguments in order for `eval` to be right.

Comment: David542, they are so much the two sides of the coin that a famous book has that picture [on its cover](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) (in a hand of the wizard there). it also [appears that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910496/849891) in the original 1958 LISP paper by John McCarthy. I believe I also used that in that recent [answer about implementing `apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68037807/849891) by enclosing each already-evaluated value in a `quote` before passing them to `eval`. (indeed; @amalloy) that's why null environment is enough