# Does "map" necessarily produce an additional level of nesting?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

Does using nested `map`s automatically create another level of nesting? Here is a basic example that I used:

```
; One level
(map (lambda (x1)
   "Hi")
 '(1))

; Two levels
(map (lambda (x1)
   (map (lambda (x2)
          "Hi")
        '(1)))
     '(1))

; Three levels
(map (lambda (x1)
   (map (lambda (x2)
      (map (lambda (x3)
          "Hi")
           '(1)))
        '(1)))
     '(1))

; Four levels
(map (lambda (x1)
   (map (lambda (x2)
      (map (lambda (x3)
         (map (lambda (x4)
          "Hi")
           '(1)))
        '(1)))
     '(1)))
   '(1))
```

```
("Hi")
(("Hi"))
((("Hi")))
(((("Hi"))))
```

Or, are there any counterexamples where adding another `map` will not produce additional nesting? I'm having trouble 'getting' how `map` adds another level. For example, for the first level:

```
(map (lambda (x1)
   "Hi")
 '(1))
```

I understand that there is one element in the list, and 'for each element' in the list -- we will return the element `"Hi"`at that position in the list, so for the first level we get `("Hi")`.

But then how, for example, from the list `("Hi")` do we get a nested list at the second level? I know I've asked a lot of questions related to `map` and nesting, but hopefully if I can just understand the going from `1` level to `2` I can figure out the rest...

Comment: `map` returns a list of the results. If you nest them, you get a nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**one-to-one**

Your examples include `(map (lambda (x) x) ...)`

```scm
(map (lambda (ignore-me)
       (map (lambda (x) x) ; <- no-op
            '(1 2 3)))
     '(1))
```

```
((1 2 3))
```

It's "hard to see" because the inner `map` is essentially a no-op. `map` creates a **1:1** relationship between the input and the output, with no opinions about what the mapping procedure does. If the mapping procedure returns a single element, a list, or a very nested list, it doesn't matter -

```scm
(map (lambda (ignore-me)
       '(1 2 3))
     '(foo))
```

```
((1 2 3))
```

```scm
(map (lambda (_)
       '(((((really nested))))))
     '(1 2 3))
```

```
((((((really nested)))))
 (((((really nested)))))
 (((((really nested))))))
```

Or with some ascii visualization -

```scm
(define (fn x) (+ x x))

(map fn '(1 2 3))
;          \ \ \
;           \ \ (fn 3)
;            \ \      \
;             \ (fn 2) \
;              \      \ \
;               (fn 1) \ \
;                     \ \ \
;  output:           '(2 4 6)
```

Should you choose to `map` inside of the mapping procedure to another `map` call -

```scm
(map (lambda (...)
       (map ...)) ; <- nested map
     ...)
```

The same rules apply. Each `map` output has a **1:1** relationship with its input list. We can imagine `map`'s type for more insight -

```
map : ('a -> 'b, 'a list) -> 'b list
       --------  -------     -------
         \        \           \_ returns a list of type 'b
          \        \
           \        \__ input list of type 'a
            \
             \__ mapping procedure, maps
                 one element of type 'a
                 to one element of type 'b
```

---

**implementing map**

As a learning exercise, it's useful to implement `map` to gain an intimate understanding of how it works -

```scm
(define (map fn lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (fn (car lst))
            (map fn (cdr lst)))))

(map (lambda (x)
       (list x x x x x))
     '(1 2 3))
```

```
((1 1 1 1 1)
 (2 2 2 2 2)
 (3 3 3 3 3))
```

As you can see, `map` does not have an opinion on the type of elements in `lst` or what the return value of `fn` is. `map` plainly passes the `car` of the list to `fn` and `cons`'es it onto the recursive result of the `cdr` of the list.

---

**append-map**

Another relevant procedure we should look at is `append-map` -

```
append-map : ('a -> 'b list, 'a list) -> 'b list
              -------------  -------     -------
                \             \           \_ returns a list of type 'b
                 \             \_ input list of type 'a
                  \
                   \_ mapping function, maps
                      one element of type 'a
                      to a LIST of elements of type 'b
```

The only difference here is the mapping procedure is expected to return a **list** of elements, not just a single element. In this way, `append-map` creates a **1:many** relationship between in the input list and the output list.

```scm
(append-map (lambda (x)
              (list x x x x x))
            '(1 2 3))
```

```
(1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3)
```

This characteristic of `append-map` is why it is sometimes called `flatmap`, as it "flattens" a level of nesting -

```scm
(append-map (lambda (x)
              (map (lambda (y)
                     (list x y))
                   '(spade heart club diamond)))
            '(J Q K A))
```

```
((J spade)
 (J heart)
 (J club)
 (J diamond)
 (Q spade)
 (Q heart)
 (Q club)
 (Q diamond)
 (K spade)
 (K heart)
 (K club)
 (K diamond)
 (A spade)
 (A heart)
 (A club)
 (A diamond))
```

---

Follow-up exercises for the reader:

- What would the output be if we traded `append-map` for `map` in the example above?
- Define `map` in another way or two. Verify the correct behaviour
- Define `append-map` in terms of `map`. Define it again without using `map`.

---

**loose typing**

Scheme is an untyped language and thus a list's contents are not required to be homogenous. Still, it's useful to think about `map` and `append-map` in this way as the type helps communicate how the function will behave. Here are more accurate type definitions provided by Racket -

```
(map proc lst ...+) → list?
  proc : procedure?
  lst : list?
```

```
(append-map proc lst ...+) → list?
  proc : procedure?
  lst : list?
```

These are much looser and do reflect the loose programs you can actually write. For example -

```scm
(append-map (lambda (x)
              (list 'a-symbol "hello" 'float (* x 1.5) 'bool (> x 1)))
            '(1 2 3))
```

```
(a-symbol "hello" float 1.5 bool #f a-symbol "hello" float 3.0 bool #t a-symbol "hello" float 4.5 bool #t)
```

---

**variadic map and append-map**

Do you see those `...+` in the types above? For the sake of simplicity, I've been hiding an important detail up until this point. The variadic interface of `map` means that it can accept 1 **or more** input lists -

```scm
(map (lambda (x y z)
       (list x y z))
     '(1 2 3)
     '(4 5 6)
     '(7 8 9))
```

```
((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
```

```scm
(append-map (lambda (x y z)
              (list x y z))
            '(1 2 3)
            '(4 5 6)
            '(7 8 9))
```

```
(1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9)
```

Follow-up exercises for the reader:

- Define variadic `map`
- Define variadic `append-map`

---

**a touch of lambda calculus**

You are aware of lambda calculus. Did you know `(lambda (x y z) (list x y z)` is the same as `list`? This is known as [Eta reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction) -

```scm
(map list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
```

```
((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
```

```scm
(append-map list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
```

```
(1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9)
```

---

**delimited continuations**

[Remember when](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68013312/633183) we talked about [delimited continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation) and operators `shift` and `reset`? After learning about `append-map`, let's see `amb`, the [ambiguous choice operator](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Elczhang/324/files/notes/02-amb-continuations.pdf) -

```scm
(define (amb . lst)
  (shift k (append-map k lst)))
```

We can use `amb` like this -

```scm
(reset (list (amb 'J 'Q 'K 'A) (amb '♡ '♢ '♤ '♧)))
```

```
(J ♡ J ♢ J ♤ J ♧ Q ♡ Q ♢ Q ♤ Q ♧ K ♡ K ♢ K ♤ K ♧ A ♡ A ♢ A ♤ A ♧)
```

```scm
(reset (list (list (amb 'J 'Q 'K 'A) (amb '♡ '♢ '♤ '♧))))
```

```
((J ♡) (J ♢) (J ♤) (J ♧) (Q ♡) (Q ♢) (Q ♤) (Q ♧) (K ♡) (K ♢) (K ♤) (K ♧) (A ♡) (A ♢) (A ♤) (A ♧))
```

In a more useful example, we use the `pythag`orean theorem to `find-right-triangles` -

```scm
(define (pythag a b c)
  (= (+ (* a a) (* b b)) (* c c))) ; a² + b² = c²

(define (find-right-triangles . side-lengths)
  (filter ((curry apply) pythag)
          (reset (list
                   (list (apply amb side-lengths)
                         (apply amb side-lengths)
                         (apply amb side-lengths))))))

(find-right-triangles 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
```

```
((3 4 5) (4 3 5) (6 8 10) (8 6 10))
```

Delimited continuations effectively turn your program inside-out, allowing you to focus on declarative structure -

```scm
(define (bit)
  (amb #\0 #\1))

(define (4-bit)
  (reset (list (string (bit) (bit) (bit) (bit)))))

(4-bit)
```

```
("0000" "0001" "0010" "0011" "0100" "0101" "0110" "0111" "1000" "1001" "1010" "1011" "1100" "1101" "1110" "1111")
```

`amb` can be used anywhere in any expression to evaluate the expression once per supplied value. This limitless use can yield extraordinary results -

```scm
(reset
  (list
    (if (> 5 (amb 6 3))
        (string-append "you have "
                       (amb "dark" "long" "flowing")
                       " "
                       (amb "hair" "sentences"))
        (string-append "please do not "
                       (amb "steal" "hurt")
                       " "
                       (amb "any" "other")
                       " "
                       (amb "people" "animals")))))
```

```
("please do not steal any people"
 "please do not steal any animals"
 "please do not steal other people"
 "please do not steal other animals"
 "please do not hurt any people"
 "please do not hurt any animals"
 "please do not hurt other people"
 "please do not hurt other animals"
 "you have dark hair"
 "you have dark sentences"
 "you have long hair"
 "you have long sentences"
 "you have flowing hair"
 "you have flowing sentences")
```

Comment: surely this one is not "nebulous" in any way. :)

Comment: "exceeds comment limit" lmao :D

Answer (score 3):

`map` collects the return values of all the function calls, and wraps them in another list.

If the function returns a list, you'll get a list of lists.

So if you have nested maps, you always get nested lists as the final result. And each level of mapping adds another level of nesting.

Note that this is only true if you're actually returning the value of `map` at each level. You could do other things with it, e.g.

```
;; Two levels
(map (lambda (x1)
       (length (map (lambda (x2)
                      "Hi")
                    '(1))))
     '(1))
```

This will return `(1)`

Answer (score 2):

The `map` will return a list for each element in that list. Let us go through a multi-map example where we can show how nesting comes into play.

First, let's do a single `map` on a sequence of numbers and "do nothing" to them. That is, just return the element from the input:

```lisp
(map (lambda (x) x)
     '(1 2 3))
; (1 2 3)
```

At this point, it may be easy to think that another level of nesting should not occur if we add on another `map` since here we have not 'nested' the input list. It has simply 'stayed' at `(1 2 3)`.

But if we add an outer level, we can see how this may occur:

```
(map (lambda (ignore-me)
       (map (lambda (x) x)
            '(1 2 3)))
     '(1))
; (( 1 2 3 ))
```

With just one 'outer-element' it's hard to see this, but instead, let's add 5 outer elements and make it much easier to spot:

```
(map (lambda (ignore-me)
       (map (lambda (x) x)
            '(1 2 3)))
     '(5 5 5 5 5))
;(
;  (1 2 3) 
;  (1 2 3) 
;  (1 2 3) 
;  (1 2 3) 
;  (1 2 3)
;)
```

Here we can see **for each** outer element -- and there are five of them -- we are returning the "inner-result" -- which is `(1 2 3)` in the above case. If we did the same thing again, this time producing two additional outer loops, we can see a similar result occurring:

```
(map (lambda (ignore-me1)
(map (lambda (ignore-me2)
       (map (lambda (x) x)
            '(1 2 3)))
     '(5 5 5 5 5)))
     '(2 2))
; (
;   ((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3)) 
;   ((1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3))
; )
```

Comment: Very nice and detailed.