# Converting this map into a for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, nested-loops, map-function

What would be the proper conversion of the following `map` statement into a `for` loop?

```py
map(lambda x: map(lambda y: map(lambda z: x*y*z, [5,6]), [3,4]), [1,2])
# [[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```

My first attempt was something like:

```py
x_tmp = []
for x in [1,2]:
    y_tmp = []
    for y in [3,4]:
        z_tmp = []
        for z in [5,6]:
            z_tmp.append(x*y*z)
        y_tmp.append(z_tmp)
    x_tmp.append(y_tmp)

x_tmp
# [[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```

But this seems so odd that I can't imagine that would be the actual translation of it. Is there something closer to how `map` works that can be shown with a `for` loop?

I thought maybe it would be close to:

```
[x*y*z for x in [1,2] for y in [3,4] for z in [5,6]]
# [15, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 48]
```

But that seems to lose all the nesting and do a flat mapping instead.

To do the list-comprehension way it seems not only does it need to be nested, but the args also need to be reversed, for example:

```py
>>> [[[x*y*z for z in [5,6]] for y in [3,4]] for x in [1,2]]
# [[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```

Comment: A list comprehension always returns a single list. If you want nested lists, you use nested list comprehensions.

Comment: In terms of the order of operations, nothing is actually "reversed": in all the snippets that give the correct result, the inner loop is always the one for the `z` variable.

Comment: "But this seems so odd that I can't imagine that would be the actual translation of it. Is there something closer to how map works that can be shown with a for loop?" why does it seem "odd"? That's it.

Comment: The (correct) list comprehension is nested, but that's normal given that both the regular loops are also nested, as is the nested `map` statement. About the parameter order: The "reading direction" is different, but again, the actual ordering of the parameters is the same as in the `map` or nested loop blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which REPL you are using, but `map` returns an iterator in Python 3.

```py
x = map(lambda x: map(lambda y: map(lambda z: x*y*z, [5,6]), [3,4]), [1,2])

print(x)
```

```py
<map object at 0x7fd6f70d1670>
```

You can use `list` to convert the iterator to a list -

```py
print(list(x))
```

```py
[<map object at 0x7fd6f7034f70>, <map object at 0x7fd6f70837f0>]
```

As you can see, the nested `map` calls produce iterators as well, so you would need to call `list` on the nested elements to get the actual output in your question

```py
x = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: list(map(lambda z: x*y*z, [5,6])), [3,4])), [1,2]))

print(x)
```

```py
[[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```

You could write a `nested_for` that takes a `proc` and a variable count of iterables, `its` -

```py
def nested_for(proc, *its):
  def loop (acc, its):
    if not its:
      yield proc(*acc)
    else:
      for x in its[0]:
        yield list(loop((*acc, x), its[1:]))
  yield from loop(tuple(), its)
```

```py
out = list(nested_for(lambda x,y,z: x*y*z, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))
print(out)
```

```py
[[[[15], [18]], [[20], [24]]], [[[30], [36]], [[40], [48]]]]
```

This implementation produces one additional level of `[...]` nesting. If that is undesirable, you can make the `loop` a bit more sophisticated -

```py
def nested_for(proc, *its):
  def loop (acc, it = None, *its):
    if not it:
      yield proc(*acc)
    elif not its:
      for v in it:
        yield proc(*acc, v) # don't nest deepest iteration
    else:
      for v in it:
        yield list(loop((*acc, v), *its))
  yield from loop(tuple(), *its)
```

```py
out = list(nested_for(lambda x,y,z: x*y*z, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))
print(out)
```

```py
[[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```

Seeing as though you are [familiar with currying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68013312/633183), you could simplify `nested_for` by making it accept a curried `proc` -

```py
def nested_for (proc, it = None, *its):
  if not it:
    return
  elif not its:
    for v in it:
      yield proc(v)
  else:
    for v in it:
      yield list(nested_for(proc(v), *its))
```

```py
out = list(nested_for(lambda x: lambda y: lambda z: x*y*z, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))
print(out)
```

```py
[[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```

Aside from that I don't really know what question you're trying to answer. As Prune points out, you've already identified the equivalent `for` and list comprehension forms.

Comment: there is an option when posting/editing an answer. i typically mark an answer as cw when the question is somewhat nebulous or when providing info that does not fit in a comment. cw-type answers are not awarded points and can be freely edited by anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Your first attempt is, indeed, an appropriate transformation to nested `for` loops.  Your final attempt is an appropriate transformation to a nested list comprehension.

I'm not sure why you find these unsatisfying; unrolling loops is often a messy business.  You've just provided a lovely primer in the equivalent forms.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

you write

> *"seems to lose all the nesting and do a flat mapping instead."*

and that's precisely the answer to your recent closed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68107356/849891) about Scheme code translated to Python.

`(apply append (map foo xs)) == (flatmap foo xs)` and `flatmap` is how nested `for` loops are translated / implemented.

to be clear: it's nested in the sense of being `[result(x,y) for x in xs for y in ys]`. the nested list comprehension in this question, `[[result for y in ys] for x in xs]` is not nested loops, it's one loop (`for x in xs`) that yields the whole inner list comprehension's value (`[result for y in ys]`) as *its* result for each `x` in `xs`.

nested loops are combined loops which yield their result as one sequence, from the deepest loop only. to emulate this with lists, `flatmap` is performed, to achieve the same effect.

so, the nested loops are -- in pseudocode, --

```
for x in xs:
   for y in ys:
      yield result(x, y)

= [result(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]

= (flatMapOn xs (lambda (x) =>
    (flatMapOn ys (lambda (y) => (list (result x y))))))

= (flatMapOn xs (lambda (x) =>
        (mapOn ys (lambda (y) =>       (result x y) ))))
```

and the "map-like" loop you ask about is

```
for x in xs: 
    yield (list (for y in ys: 
                   yield result(x,y) ))

= [[result(x, y) for y in ys] for x in xs]

= (mapOn xs (lambda (x) =>
    (mapOn ys (lambda (y) => (result x y)))))
```

NB it's `yield`, not `yield from`, in the outer loop here.

In Racket we observe

```
> (define (flatMapOn xs foo) (flatmap foo xs))

> (define (mapOn xs foo) (map foo xs))

> (display (flatMapOn (list 1 2 3) (lambda (x) 
     (flatMapOn (list x (+ x 10) (+ x 100)) (lambda (y) 
        (list (cons x y)))))))
((1 . 1) (1 . 11) (1 . 101) (2 . 2) (2 . 12) (2 . 102) 
 (3 . 3) (3 . 13) (3 . 103))

> (display (flatMapOn (list 1 2 3) (lambda (x) 
     (mapOn (list x (+ x 10) (+ x 100)) (lambda (y) 
              (cons x y))))))
((1 . 1) (1 . 11) (1 . 101) (2 . 2) (2 . 12) (2 . 102) 
 (3 . 3) (3 . 13) (3 . 103))

> (display (mapOn (list 1 2 3) (lambda (x) 
     (mapOn (list x (+ x 10) (+ x 100)) (lambda (y) 
              (cons x y))))))
( ((1 . 1) (1 . 11) (1 . 101)) 
  ((2 . 2) (2 . 12) (2 . 102)) 
  ((3 . 3) (3 . 13) (3 . 103)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def nest_op(d, p = 1):
   return [nest_op(d[:-1], p*i) if d[:-1] else p*i for i in d[-1]]

print(nest_op([[5,6], [3,4], [1,2]]))
```

Output:

```
[[[15, 18], [20, 24]], [[30, 36], [40, 48]]]
```